# Unity Google Play Saved Games

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have been trying to implement google play saved games to my game in Unity3D using the official [plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). I want to save few variables like User highscore and the number of coins user has. PlayerPrefs won't suffice as the data will get wiped out once the user uninstalls game for any reason.
I have been looking out for tutorial on this for quite some time but in vain.
I have been through Unity serialization and de-serialization stuff. So if anyone can help me out with saving and retrieving variables from google play saved games.
I have been through the documentation but I cannot understand much from it and yeah I am using C#.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#saving-game-state-to-the-cloud), its pretty self-explanatory.

Updating with code snippets :

To Init Google play :

```
using GooglePlayGames;
    using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
    using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        // enables saving game progress.
        .EnableSavedGames()

        .Build();

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    // recommended for debugging:
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    // Activate the Google Play Games platform
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

To sign in(call this in a Start(), after you have activated the platform) :

```
 Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        // handle success or failure
    });
```

From here on please read the documentation detailing how to read and write save games to the cloud.  That part can be found [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#opening-a-saved-game). Read the code and adapt it to your specific use case. I cant write it for you.

Comment: I have been through the documentation but I do not want to show the load game screen. What i want is the following work flow :-  1. User starts game. 2. Automatic google play games sign in. 3. Automatically load the number of coins the user has and his highscore. 4. On game over, automatically save the number of coins and highscore.

Comment: @Saurabh I edited my answer to help you understand better. All the code you need is in the documentation.